# move cursor in empty line (VIM)

Tags: vim

If I have a code like below,

```
sumNumbers :: [Int] -> Int
sumNumbers [] = 0

sumNumbers (x:xs) = x
```

If my cursor is at the beginning of empty line (above sumNumbers (x:xs) = x), how do I move it exactly under [] brackets. Is there any nice trick available? I am sick and tired of tabs.

Comment: One option is `:set virtualedit=all` then go to second line and type `f[j`. This will put the cursor under `[]`.

Comment: @Sergio It does not seem to work. Can you elaborate on the mechanics behind f[j?

Comment: `f[` will go to next `[` in the current line (more info in `:help f`). Then `j` will move the cursor down one line.

Comment: Thanx @Sergio. Not exactly the way how I want to do it but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without plugin:

?]

continue to search up with N

plugin option:

easymotion in vim, or acejump in ideavim.